# D3.js - Append objects outside of the selection

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do you select a div and then create a new div right below it?

```js
function addContainer(row)
{
  row++
  d3.select('body')
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', `#container${row}`)
    .attr("onclick", `addContainer(${row})`)
    .text("Container " + `${row}`)
}
```

```html
<div id="container0" onclick="addContainer(0)" >Container 0</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Everything works fine except for the part that I want the added div to be exactly below the div I clicked on and not at the very bottom. So my idea was that instead of selecting the body I select the id of the div I clicked on and then append a new div. However this adds a div within the div and not below it.

So how do I append it outside of the selection or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach to do that: Use [d3.insert](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_insert).

And due to the `this` issues while binding events `onclick` on HTML elements, I've moved the event binding and handling to the JS section.

This is how I'm appending a `<div>` as the next sibling to the selected (clicked) element:
`this.parentNode.insertBefore(this.cloneNode(deep), this.nextSibling)`

Code:

```js
d3.select('#container0').on('click', addContainer);

function addContainer(row)
  {
    if(!row) row = 0;
    row++
    d3.select(this).select(function () {
      return this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement('div'), this.nextSibling);
    })
      .attr('class', `#container${row}`)
      .on('click', function () { addContainer.call(this, row); })
      .text("Container " + `${row}`)
  }
```

```html
<div id="container0">Container 0</div>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Notice the `addContainer.call(this, row)` to bind the `this` used while selection.

Hope this helps. And about the container **number**, it adds +1 to the bound element's number. If you want the container **number** to keep on increasing, just declare the `row` outside and take it out while calling the function (as this'll help the `div`s to have unique IDs). And do check the DOM if it's inserting the elements correctly.